# How to add HEIC image to iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I'm trying to pass an HEIC image file to the iOS simulator, I'm trying to do it because I need to verify why my app isn't working with HEIC images, but I only have an IPhone 6 (IPhone 7 or newer is required, that's why I need to use the iOS Simulator).

I used this command: `xcrun simctl addmedia booted ./IMG_0237.HEIC` and it failed with the error shown in the image below, but worked with a JPG image.

Is there a way to put HEIC images on ios Simulator?

[image: commands executed]

Comment: The same helpful "Cocoa error -1" appears if you drag&drog a HEIC image on the simulator (drag&drop of jpeg images works)

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: Adding HEIC images either by drag&drop or `xcrun simctl addmedia` finally works with Xcode 9.3 beta and the iPhone X 11.3 simulator.

You can put a HEIC file on iCloud, login on the simulator, and access it from there. There doesn't appear to be a way to get it into the gallery (Photo app) though. That is: I did manage to increment the counter in the Photo app and have a grey rectangle appear as additional photo. But at least the iPhone X  11.2 simulator doesn't seem to be capable of displaying HEIC images. It seems like the simulator is useless to test actual device behaviour.